# how to do show hide for multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have did the code for one category so i need to do same thing for another categories using with same code... can suggest any shortest format for using multiple category containers.

ex: my symbols is one category so i need to do the such a way for another category that is "my dollars'

Jquery

```
$('.my-symbols .show').click(function(){
 $('.my-symbols .container').show(500);
 });
 $('.my-symbols .hide').click(function(){
 $('.my-symbols .container').hide(300);
 });
```

css

```
#charts .my-symbols{
width:59%;
float:left;
margin-left:0.5%;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background:#666666;
padding:0.5%;
}
#charts .my-symbols .show{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background:url(../../images/blockopen.png) no-repeat;
float:right;
/*padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;*/
border:none;
top:-10px;
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
position:relative;
}
#charts .my-symbols .hide{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background:url(../../images/blockclose.png) no-repeat;
position:relative;
top:0;
right:0;
float:right;
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border:none;
} 
#charts .my-symbols .container{
display:none;
position:absolute;
padding:1%;
background:#454545;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: how is your HTML markup look like? can you post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and show us?

Comment: hi please check it this following link.. http://jsfiddle.net/qhnNn/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add another class to all category items, lets call it category. Then based on the DOM-structure revealed by the CSS you have provided, I guess you could do something like this:

```
$('.category .show').click(function(){
   $(this).parents(".category").find(".container").show(500);
});
$('.category .hide').click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".category").find(".container").hide(300);
});
```

**Edit**

Added a fiddle that uses my example, with two categories:
http://jsfiddle.net/coffe_e/c8Tgf/1/